# Can't use EXTERNAL authentication after enabling TLS in ldap-2.4

Tags: openldap, sasl

I used the following LDIF file to activate the TLS support for the LDAP server:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: NORMAL 
-
add: olcTLSCRLCheck
olcTLSCRLCheck: none
-
add: olcTLSVerifyClient
olcTLSVerifyClient: never
-
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/CA.crt
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/key.pem
```

and force the TLS usage for the client connections with the following LDIF:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSecurity
olcSecurity: tls=1
```

After this I can't use the "-Y EXTERNAL" any more to read or modify the configuration schema. For example I get SASL error if I run:

```
$ sudo ldapsearch -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "" -LLL -s base -Z supportedSASLMechanisms
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Authentication method not supported (7)
    additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available:
```

and if I check for supported SASL mechanisms:

```
$ sudo ldapsearch -x -H ldapi:/// -b "" -LLL -s base -Z supportedSASLMechanisms
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: DIGEST-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: CRAM-MD5
supportedSASLMechanisms: NTLM
supportedSASLMechanisms: PLAIN
supportedSASLMechanisms: LOGIN
```

I really can't see the EXTERNAL included in the list. What am I missing here?

This is on Ubuntu-12.04 and slapd-2.4.31.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without access to the running config, you'll have to stop `slapd` and edit the configuration offline.

1. stop `slapd`: `service slapd stop`
2. dump the config database to a text file: `slapcat -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -b cn=config -l config.ldif`
3. move the existing config database out of the way: `mv /etc/ldap/slapd.d{,.old}`
4. make a new, empty config database:

   `mkdir /etc/ldap/slapd.d
   chown --reference=/etc/ldap/slapd.d.old /etc/ldap/slapd.d
   chmod --reference=/etc/ldap/slapd.d.old /etc/ldap/slapd.d`
5. edit the dumped `config.ldif` to remove your `olcSecurity` setting (or add `olcRootDN` and `olcRootPW` to `cn=config`, or any other changes you like)
6. load the edited LDIF into the new empty database: `slapadd -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -b cn=config -l config.ldif`

(The above assumes your configuration lives at `/etc/ldap/slapd.d`, which is the default in Debian and Ubuntu.)

Note that `slapadd` of a complete LDIF should always be done into an empty database; so if you make a mistake and `slapadd` fails, make sure to clear out the partial database before trying again.

You can find more information in [the OpenLDAP Admin Guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/) as well as the relevant man pages.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the code: on the server side, in [servers/slapd/daemon.c](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;hb=refs/heads/OPENLDAP_REL_ENG_2_4;f=servers/slapd/daemon.c#l1952), the authid for EXTERNAL is set up using the uid and gid shortly after the incoming connection is `accept()`ed. Later on, in [servers/slapd/connection.c](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;hb=refs/heads/OPENLDAP_REL_ENG_2_4;f=servers/slapd/connection.c#l1400), if TLS is active, it overwrites that with the name from the client's certificate. Since you aren't providing a client certificate, at this point the authid gets overwritten with NULL, making EXTERNAL not available.

In short, if TLS is active then the uid+gid authid is not used. Depending on your perspective, this could be considered a bug; ideally it would fall back to the peercred ID.

That said, TLS on ldapi is really not necessary as the local socket already provides total privacy; so you could set `olcSecurity` just on your own database, leaving it not set for the frontend and `cn=config` (see e.g. [this post](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201212/msg00230.html)), or you could use `ssf=` instead of `tls=` and set `olcLocalSSF` appropriately. Or you could use a different DN as the manager for `cn=config`, in order to not depend on the peercred feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks rtandy. I really didn't want to set it on ldapi but was not aware of the fact it is going to be affected too.

The problem is the EXTERNAL was the only way I could modify the `cn=config` so since I've lost that access and haven't created another `cn=config` admin as suggested, is there any other way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using ldappi:///  instead of ldap:// solved the issue for me after activating starttls on my system

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://  -f pwd2.ldif
```

works whereas

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -f pwd2.ldif
```

reported

> SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s:
>   Unknown authentication method (-6)    additional info: SASL(-4): no
>   mechanism available: